# "Each is to blame" or "each are to blame"

Tags: verb-agreement

Each of the tasks from the Patient Task panel illustrated previously is shown on the Tasks tab of the Visit.

Each of the tasks from the Patient Task panel illustrated previously are shown on the Tasks tab of the Visit.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each *is* shown. Each is singular and requires a singular verb.

What's making you twitch is that tasks are plural and each is singular. You might avoid this by saying, "All of the tasks ... are shown".